# Regex for string with dots and without special characters or space

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need regex that allows at least 2  and at most 4 dots. The string can't start or end with a dot. Special characters like `_ , * # $` etc. aren't allowed.

The string must be of the format `string.string.string` Optionally, it could have more than 3 items (where dot is the item delimiter).

Strings like `.string1.`, `string1.string2`, `string1. string2.  string3` and `str#ing1.strin*g2.str$ing3` are not allowed.

For a start I've tried: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`, but I don't want to start with dot. I added   `^[^\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$` and I want to have dot after the first string so I made this   [^.]+`([a-zA-Z0-9])([\.]{1})`.

It accepts characters like # instead of a-zA-Z and numbers 0-9 so I get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^(?i)[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+){2,4}$
```

You can play with the input in the [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kD2cY7/2).

Comment: Thx very much for answer and references. It's pretty difficult for me to make clear question in english and I really don't get the minus score when I am new to something and I don't know how to do it. I was looking for answer on the Internet for hours. Thanks for people like you - willing to help.

Comment: Thanks one more time. The demo is really helpful.

Comment: Really simple and effective +1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+){2,4}$
```

The '?:' at the beginning of the group means it's a non-capture group.
{2,4} means the previous group has to be repeated between 2 and 4 times.

Comment: Underscores are not allowed. `\w` matches underscores.

Comment: `\w` can be replaces by any set of characters, like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. It wasn't really the complex part of the question. Using `\w` makes the overall concept a bit more clear for anyone else that is viewing the question.

Comment: Be careful with the `\w` class in C#, because it doesn't only contains `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` as several other flavors. In .NET this class contains all unicode letters and digits. The global structure of the pattern is indeed here.